# struct nested in union nested in struct in C

Tags: c++, struct, nested, unions

I want to demonstrate an employee class who can have two types of payments; salaried or hourly. Based on user input, the employee's pay type is defined and I use one of the sructs in the union. I wrote this code for it:

```
struct Employee {
    int Id;
    char Dept;
    int Age;
    char PayClass;
    union PayType
    {
        struct Salaried {
            float MonthlyRate;
            int StartDate;
        } salaried;
        struct Hourly {
            float RatePerHour;
            int RegHours;
            int OvertimeHours;
        } hourly;
    } u;
};
```

The only way I can initialize fields in `Salaried` or `Hourly` is by writing the following:

```
int main()
{
    Employee emp;
    printf("Enter your ID?\n");
    cin >> emp.Id;
    printf("Enter your department:\nM for Math\nP for physics\nC for computer engineering\n");
    cin >> emp.Dept;
    printf("Enter your age\n");
    cin >> emp.Age;
    printf("Enter your pay type:\nS for salaried\nH for hourly");
    cin >> emp.PayClass;
    if (emp.PayClass == 'S') {
        printf("Enter your monthly rate\n");
        cin >> emp.u.salaried.MonthlyRate;
        //and other fields of Salaried struct
    }
    else {
        //initialize fields of Hourly struct
    }
}
```

Is this line `cin >> emp.u.salaried.MonthlyRate;` the best and most true way I can do this?

Comment: That's C++, not C.

Comment: Since you are writing C++, you might consider an abstract base class and concrete classes that deal with how the Employee is paid.

Comment: Why can't `Salaried` and `Hourly` inherit fro the same base `PayType` class? That's how C++ does it.

Comment: Depends on what you consider best.

Comment: @tadman it’s a student project and the professor said I have to use unions and structs

Comment: To be honest the vast majority of C++ professors have no clue what they're talking about, so do what you can to pass the assignment but be aware that there's a C++ pattern for doing this that's the polar opposite. This is "fancy C", as taught by many teachers, not actually C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your way of accessing the **MonthlyRate** is acceptable but if you want a cleaner way, you should use a mutator/setter.
I have also inserted a condition which will check if the **MonthlyRate** is positive or not.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    struct Employee {
        int Id;
        char Dept;  
        int Age;
        char PayClass;
        union PayType
        {
            struct Salaried {
            float MonthlyRate;
            int StartDate;
        } salaried;
            struct Hourly {
            float RatePerHour;
            int RegHours;
            int OvertimeHours;
        } hourly;
    } u;
    //- This Setter should do the trick
    void setMonthlyRate() {
        cin >> u.salaried.MonthlyRate;
        if (u.salaried.MonthlyRate < 0) {
            cerr << "Error! Invalid Input!" << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    Employee emp;
    printf("Enter your ID?\n");
    cin >> emp.Id;
    printf("Enter your department:\nM for Math\nP for physics\nC for computer engineering\n");
    cin >> emp.Dept;
    printf("Enter your age\n");
    cin >> emp.Age;
    printf("Enter your pay type:\nS for salaried\nH for hourly");
    cin >> emp.PayClass;
    if (emp.PayClass == 'S') {
        printf("Enter your monthly rate\n");
        //cin >> emp.u.salaried.MonthlyRate;
        emp.setMonthlyRate();
        //and other fields of Salaried struct
    }
    else {
        //initialize fields of Hourly struct
    }
}
```